# SQL Server 2016/2019 mixed AG causing constant DB transaction log growth

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

We have a SQL Server 2016 Always On Availability Group (AG) setup with 3 nodes and recently added 3 new nodes with SQL Server 2019.

After the addition of the new nodes, we noticed that the database transaction log files are constantly growing and never reducing, even after attempting to shrink the log file and taking a manual backup of the log file. The databases from SQL Server 2019 show as "(Synchronizing/In Recovery)".

The AG is healthy, and the Last Hardened Time and Last Redone Time all appear to be the latest. We also have hourly purge jobs and TLog backups in place, but they do not seem to be helping in this case.

Is this behavior expected when running SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019 together in an AG? Do we need to configure any specific settings to prevent log file growth until we failover all SQL Server 2016 instances to SQL Server 2019?

- Validated AG health, Last hardened time and Last Redone Time all looks latest.
- Tried to shrink the Log files, not much space being released.
- Log is not truncating, possible reason could be the commit from SQL Server 2019 to 2016 not happening

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#ServerInstance), *Each server instance must be running the same version of SQL Server to participate in an availability group.*. Mixing versions participating in an AG is not supported.

Comment: What does `SELECT database_id, name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases` show?